# Combining tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a horribly designed database that has procedures in it that generate new tables every week, and has been doing so for a couple of years. It's got a SQL script that gets 200+ columns of data via queries on various tables, dumps it all into a single table called Selections, and then after it's done you have to manually rename that table (Selections_Week001, Selections_Week002, etc) every week. Now we have around 100+ tables. What I want to do is put all that data into one table, with a column indicating its original source table (001, 002, etc), so I can then get rid of all those individual tables. Is there a way to do this using some SQL script, or am I going to have to manually edit and run 100 append queries?

Comment: You could union them all together in one query and do one insert but that's going to be a killer if you've got a lot of data going on. I'd create a script that does them a table at a time (you can easily create loads of scripts in something like excel). I'd prefer the control of this over an all at once approach

Comment: My opinion: I would think about using some scripting language for this, since dynamic sql is unnecessarily haggly.

Comment: I was just hoping to write something that could dynamically grab each table name and automatically do the append for all the tables without me having to rewrite it 100 times

Comment: what difference does the original tablename make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for me worked well at test data:

```
select * 
into Selections_Total
from Selections_Week001
where 1=0
alter table Selections_Total
add Original_Table varchar(64)

--select * From Selections_Total

declare @sql varchar(max)
select @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' UNION ALL select *, ''' + name + ''' from ', 'select *, ''' + name + ''' from ') + name
from sys.tables where name like 'Selections_Week%'

--select @sql
insert into Selections_Total
exec(@sql)
```

**UPD:** missed  `with a column indicating its original source table`  at first. Now fixed.

Comment: "`where 1=0`" --- what is this supposed to do?

Comment: select 0 rows from table to copy only structure

Comment: Nice, that works well on the tables I have, thanks for the help, Andrey!